# Redirect Junos IP public -> IP private

Tags: bgp, juniper

we have an MX204 here that works as our BGP, border router and it is gateway of a service that has private IP, I need to access this service with private IP outside our network, you can tell me if I do this will have some problem In MX204 and how do I do this, could anyone give me some tips?